# ORA-01007: variable not in select list-1007

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE req1_tb(TableName  VARCHAR2(43),
                    ColumnName  VARCHAR2(98),
                    Edit_ind    CHAR)
```

Here's the dml for this table:

```
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','employee_id','Y');
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','first_name','Y');
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','last_name','N');
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','email','N');
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','job_id','N');
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','salary','Y');
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','commission_pct','Y');
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','hire_date','N');
insert into req1_tb VALUES('Employees','department_id','Y');
```

I assumed that edit_ind column in `enter code here` below table will change dynamically

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM REQ1_TB;

TABLENAME                                   COLUMNNAME      EDIT_IND
------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------
Employees                                   employee_id     Y
Employees                                   first_name      Y
Employees                                   last_name       N
Employees                                   email           N
Employees                                   job_id          N
Employees                                   salary          Y
Employees                                   commission_pct  Y
Employees                                   hire_date       N
Employees                                   department_id   Y
```

I have created procedure that will dynamically print columns who are marked 'Y' only:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dyn_sql_sp
 AS
  cols     VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_cols   VARCHAR2(2000);
  cls      VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_employee_id number;
  emp       employees%rowtype;
  cnt       number;
 cursor tab_c
 is
  select columnname from req1_tb
  where EDIT_IND='Y';
 cursor col_c
 is
  select employee_id from employees;
 BEGIN
 for i in tab_C
 loop
 cols:=cols||'emp.'||i.columnname||',';
 end loop;
 cols:=rtrim(cols,',');
for i in col_c
 loop
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || cols || ' FROM employees WHERE employee_id = :1'
INTO emp
USING i.employee_id;
 end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line(cols);
  Exception
  When Others Then
  dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm||sqlcode);
  end;
/
```

While executing I got the following error:

```
SQL> exec dyn_sql_sp;
ORA-01007: variable not in select list-1007
```

Comment: What does your employees table look like? Has it got all of those columns in it and is it in the emp schema?

Answer (score 1):

In your procedure the below code is going to create problem. As far i understand you are trying to select `columns` of table `employee` depending on `'Y'` flag from table `req1_tb`.

***Problematic Part:***

```
for i in col_c
 loop
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || cols || ' FROM employees WHERE employee_id = :1'

 --***The INTO clause is problematic here. Since the you select list is not*** having all the columns same as your cursor variable. 
INTO emp

USING i.employee_id;
 end loop;
```

Now, you are not trying the same logic while declaring a variable to hold the data returned from those selected columns in `Execute Immediate` statement.

For that the variable declaration should also be dynamic. So you declaration

> emp       employees%rowtype;

should be such that it also have all the selected columns satisfying condition flag `'Y'`. You cannot insert few columns selected from your select statement to a cursor variable having all the columns.

Comment: Also there is need to add an alias "emp" to employees table as "emp." is prefixed to all the columns in cols.  **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || cols || ' FROM employees emp WHERE employee_id = :1'**